# Testing a node-cron Job function with Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, cron, jestjs

I have a javascript class that contains a function that starts a cron job using the `node-cron` library.
But I can't seem to find a way to test the class and the function.

The variables that control the `node-cron` are in a `.env` file.
To do the testing I'm using **jest**.
My job is started when the app.js of my node application is started(the class file is imported and is export instantiated)

**.env file**

```
#CRON JOB
FREQUENCY_CRON='30 00 * * *'
TIMEZONE="America/Sao_Paulo"
SCHEDULED=true
INACTIVE_EXPIRATION_TIME=2592000000 #30 DAYS
```

**CronJob.js**

```
class CronJob {
  constructor() {
    this.startJob();
  }

  async startJob() {
    cron.schedule(
      process.env.FREQUENCY_CRON,
      async () => {
        //DO SOME DATA PROCESSING 
      },
      {
        scheduled: process.env.SCHEDULED,
        timezone: process.env.TIMEZONE
      }
    );
  }
}

export default new CronJob();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) to mock `node-cron` module. Use `dotenv` package load the environment variables from `.env` before running the test cases.

E.g.

`cronJob.js`:

```js
import cron from 'node-cron';

class CronJob {
  constructor() {
    this.startJob();
  }

  async startJob() {
    cron.schedule(
      process.env.FREQUENCY_CRON,
      async () => {
        console.log('DO SOME DATA PROCESSING');
      },
      {
        scheduled: process.env.SCHEDULED,
        timezone: process.env.TIMEZONE,
      },
    );
  }
}

export default new CronJob();
```

`cronJob.test.js`:

```js
import cron from 'node-cron';
import path from 'path';

require('dotenv').config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, './.env') });

jest.mock('node-cron', () => {
  return {
    schedule: jest.fn(),
  };
});

describe('61765291', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    cron.schedule.mockImplementationOnce(async (frequency, callback) => await callback());
    require('./cronJob');
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('DO SOME DATA PROCESSING');
    expect(cron.schedule).toBeCalledWith('30 00 * * *', expect.any(Function), {
      scheduled: 'true',
      timezone: 'America/Sao_Paulo',
    });
  });
});
```

`.env`:

```
#CRON JOB
FREQUENCY_CRON='30 00 * * *'
TIMEZONE="America/Sao_Paulo"
SCHEDULED=true
INACTIVE_EXPIRATION_TIME=2592000000 #30 DAYS
```

unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61765291/cronJob.test.js (8.148s)
  61765291
    ✓ should pass (30ms)

  console.log
    DO SOME DATA PROCESSING

      at CustomConsole.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-environment-enzyme/node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:866:25)

------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File        | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files   |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 cronJob.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.145s, estimated 10s
```

Comment: I am getting Property 'mockImplementationOnce' does not exist on type '(cronExpression: string, func: () => void, options?: ScheduleOptions) => ScheduledTask'.ts
Had to add `(cron.schedule as unknown as jest.Mock)`

Comment: You can also use the [`jest.mocked` helper](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockedtitem-t-deep--false).